# Clojure warning: "resultset-seq already exists in clojure.core"

Tags: clojure, compojure, noir

I'm new to Clojure and building a web app using the Noir framework (very similar to Compojure, in fact I think it's Compojure with a different request handler layer). I'm getting a warning when I import the JDBC library:

```
WARNING: resultset-seq already refers to: #'clojure.core/resultset-seq in namespace: webapp.models.database, being replaced by: #'clojure.java.jdbc/resultset-seq
```

Do I have to live with this warning or is there a way around it? I'm importing the JDBC library using:

```
(use 'clojure.java.jdbc)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can avoid the problem by specifying the exact bindings to be imported:

```
(use '[clojure.java.jdbc :only [insert-values transaction]])
(transaction
  (insert-values ...))
```

Another option is to `:exclude` the offending binding:

```
(use '[clojure.java.jdbc :exclude [resultset-seq]])
(transaction
  (insert-values ...))
```

You can also just use `require` instead:

```
(require '[clojure.java.jdbc :as db])
(db/transaction
  (db/insert-values ...))
```

With regard to forward compatibility, `require` is arguably safest.  Using `:only` is just slightly less clean but still a pretty good approach (and easy to fix when it breaks).  Excluding the currently offending bindings is probably the least future-proof way of fixing the problem since other conflicting bindings can appear at any time and tracking down what is imported from where can be tricky.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that out. If I end up going with the ":only" approach will it affect the result set returned by queries?

Comment: @Adam As long as you don't actually refer to `resultset-seq` explicitly anywhere, it shouldn't matter.  In theory, it is conceivable that one of `clojure.java.jdbc`'s macros expands into something that refers to `resultset-seq` in a referentially non-transparent way, but it's unlikely (and even then, I would consider it a bug).

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of options.  What this warning means is, that you are replacing an already defined symbol with a definition from different package. In this case, it looks like this is a variable that you've defined, right?  If so the easiest solution might be to just rename it in your code.

Or if you don't need the resultset-seq from clojure.java.jdbc package you can exclude it:

```
(use '[clojure.java.jdbc :exclude (resultset-seq)])
```

or better yet,

```
(use '[clojure.java.jdbc :only (f1 f2 f3)])
```

where f1, f2, f3 are the things you're actually need.

```
(use '[clojure.java.jdbc :as jdbc])
```

and then use jdbc/resultset-seq

Or you can just:

```
(require 'clojure.java.jdbc)
```

and then use clojure.java.jdbc/reusltset-seq

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other excellent answers, if you want the jdbc resultset-seq instead of the core one, you can exclude the latter from being brought into the current ns:

```
(ns foo
  (:refer-clojure :exclude [resultset-seq])
  (:use clojure.java.jdbc))
```