# Hot to fix "WARNING: any? already refers to: #'clojure.core/any? in namespace: leiningen.midje, being replaced by: #'leiningen.midje/any?"

Tags: clojure, leiningen, compojure, midje

I'm try run tests in leiningen's compojure template (`lein new compojure financeiro`), using the midje framework and receive a warning:

```
lein midje
WARNING: any? already refers to: #'clojure.core/any? in namespace: leiningen.midje, being replaced by: #'leiningen.midje/any?
nil
All checks (3) succeeded.
```

My test code `handler_test.clj`:

```clj
(ns financeiro.handler-test
  (:require
    ; [clojure.test :refer :all]
    [midje.sweet :refer :all]
    [ring.mock.request :as mock]
    [financeiro.handler :refer :all]))

; (deftest test-app
;   (testing "main route"
;     (let [response (app (mock/request :get "/"))]
;       (is (= (:status response) 200))
;       (is (= (:body response) "Hello World"))))

;   (testing "not-found route"
;     (let [response (app (mock/request :get "/invalid"))]
;       (is (= (:status response) 404)))))

(facts "'Hello World' main route"
  (fact "response status is 200"
    (let [response (app (mock/request :get "/"))]
      (:status response)=> 200))

  (fact "body text is 'Hello World'"
    (let [response (app (mock/request :get "/"))]
      (:body response)=> "Hello World")))

(facts "not-found route"
  (fact "response status is 404"
    (let [response(app (mock/request :get "/invalid"))]
      (:status response)=> 404)))
```

My project file `project.clj`:

```clj
(defproject financeiro "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :min-lein-version "2.0.0"
  :dependencies [
    [org.clojure/clojure "1.10.0"]
    [compojure "1.6.1"]
    [ring/ring-defaults "0.3.2"]
  ]
  :plugins [
    [lein-ring "0.12.5"]
  ]
  :ring {
    :handler financeiro.handler/app
  }
  :profiles {
    :dev {
      :dependencies [
        [javax.servlet/servlet-api "2.5"]
        [ring/ring-mock "0.3.2"]
        [midje "1.9.8"]
      ]
      :plugins [
        [lein-midje "3.2.1"]
      ]
    }
  }
)
```

When I run default tests with `clojure.test` (`lein test`), I not receive warning, but I when run with `midje.sweet` (`lein midje`) I receive the warning about **'namespace: leiningen.midje'** and **'replace #'clojure.core/any? to #'leiningen.midje/any?'**, I searching for solution in the web but I don't find for this especific warning *(leiningen/compojure/midje)*, I'm a beginner in clojure and midje. I'm learning now. In which file I can replace this namespace? There is simple solution to remove this warning? Or this a bug in framework midje?

**This does not disturb the execution of the tests, but it is annoying to see this message every time it's run the tests.**

Note: I tryied the previous version of midje too `[midje "1.9.6"]`, but unsuccessfully!

Comment: There's an [open issue](https://github.com/marick/lein-midje/issues/67) within the lein-midje project relating to this now. I don't believe you'll be able to fix this within your project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This particular issue was solved [in this Pull Request](https://github.com/marick/lein-midje/pull/69/files).

For the general case you can get rid of this warning (when it comes from your code) by excluding (= un-refering) the symbol you want to require from another namespace than `clojure.core`

Here is an example from a different context:

#### Warning

```clj
(ns urbest.apheleia.system.typography
  (:require [garden.units :refer [rem]]))
```

```
WARNING: rem already refers to: #'clojure.core/rem in namespace: urbest.apheleia.system.typography, being replaced by: #'garden.units/rem
```

#### No more warning

```clj
(ns urbest.apheleia.system.typography
  (:refer-clojure :exclude [rem])
  (:require [garden.units :refer [rem]]))
```

Comment: also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233434/clojure-warning-resultset-seq-already-exists-in-clojure-core?rq=1